# Run Makefile through Crontab

Tags: cron

I have a script that runs make fine from terminal but throws error when I am running through Cronjob.

The script in ypxfr.sc:

```
#!/bin/sh
make -f /var/yp/Makefile -C sc auto.nfs.sc.home  2>&1 | sed -e 's/^/\t/g'
```

The crontab -l:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
59 * * * * /var/yp/ypxfr.sc >> /var/log/ypxfr.sc.out 2>&1
```

The error that I get in ypxfr.sc.out is:

```
make: *** sc: No such file or directory.  Stop.
```

Answer (score 3):

The option `-C` tells `make` to change to that directory, in this case `sc`.

Where is this directory `sc`? You should specify an absolute path here.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been solved, I had to give the absolute path make -f /var/yp/Makefile -C /var/yp/sc auto.nfs.sc.home  2>&1 | sed -e 's/^/\t/g'

Comment: This answer is in essence the same as [RalfFriedl's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/470397/116858). You may accept his answer as solving your issue. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers